# How can I call run a jar from python while obligating it to run with SDK 1.7?

Tags: java, python, sdk, jar, batch-file

I want to wrap around a jar that gets many parameters with a python code that creates those parameters.

Say I've got :

```
java -jar parameter1 ... paramterN
```

Where N isn't that large, but is kind of a burden for a user to fill it up again and again when those parameters can be assigned automatically.

The jar is a black box , and therefore I can't changed its logic to calculate those parameters itself.

So , instead I'd like to have this :

```
python MyJarRunner.py JarPath
```

when MyJarRunner will call this Jar with the calculated parameters.

My problem is that this Jar need Java SDK 1.7 in order to run without runtime errors. How can I be sure that I will run this Jar with SDK 1.7 if exists?  This need to be run a different computers with no prior knowledge about SDK 1.7 location.

A solution with batch script might be applicable too.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using the java command, use `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe" -jar ...`

to check if the file actually exists...

```
from os import path, access, R_OK  # W_OK for write permission.
PATH='C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\'
if path.exists(PATH) and path.isfile(PATH) and access(PATH, R_OK):
    //execute
else:
    //whatever you wanna do if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: But I cant assume the jdk 1.7 is there. For example, in my computer in on "C:\Program Files\glassfish\..."

Comment: Thats only one case , there must be a way to find where SDK 1.7 is located

Comment: that is the default install directory of java, not sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

Both assume that you may write your own main class.

1. Jar is never a black box --- it is basically a zip file, so you can unpack it, add your own main class that calculates parameters, change Main-Class attribute in MANIFEST.MF and you are done.
2. Consider other deployment alternatives like java webstart that allows you to download couple of jars (not only black box jar but others that you have written) specify JDK version and other things.